# Как работает cost threshold for parallelism?

Tags: sql-server

В справке написано, что это пороговое значение стоимости при котором сервер строит параллельные запросы.

А на какую конкретно стоимость он смотрит и в каких единицах она измеряется?

Вот я смотрю на план запросов и вижу, что у меня узел параллельного поиска в кластеризованном индексе стоит 58%.

Answer (score 2):

Оценочную стоимость запроса можно увидеть на крайнем левом операторе плана запроса:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Стоимость измеряется в "попугаях", то есть это некое агрегированное значение, которое можно применить для сравнения запросов друг с другом. Абсолютное значение этого показателя когда-то в прошлом рассматривалось как время в секундах на выполнение запроса, но сейчас это точно не так.

Не ищите привязки к какому-то показателю - попугаи, просто попугаи!

Comment: Получается, что этот параметр настраивается методом тыка?

Comment: В общем да, устанавливается какой-то выведенный эмпирически порог (очевидно больший, чем 5 по-умолчанию) и затем корректируется по результатам работы системы в большую или меньшую сторону, если нужно.

Comment: @iluxa1810, можете воспользоваться [методикой](https://www.scarydba.com/2017/02/28/determining-the-cost-threshold-for-parallelism/)

Comment: @i-one если сделаете локализацию и в ответ вставите оттуда выдержки, то, наверное, это может быть хорошим ответом.